# Data extraction using xPath from XML file in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying for couple of days with different combination but able to extract value from the XML file .
The xml file is in tabular form . Looking to is source file I could tried  its xPath , but it returns 'imported content is empty.'

Xpath

```
=importxml( http://reports.ieso.ca/public/IntertieScheduleFlow/PUB_IntertieScheduleFlow.xml,
/IMODocument/IMODocHeader/DocConfClass/IMODocBody/IntertieZone[1]/Actuals/Actual[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of your formula is just slightly off

1. you need to include double quotes around both the url and the xPath
2. I also don't see that xpath anywhere in the doc, but you can pull in the data using the `importdata` function instead:

```
=IMPORTDATA("http://reports.ieso.ca/public/IntertieScheduleFlow/PUB_IntertieScheduleFlow.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks, Ruben. Using IMPORTDATA, I can extract the whole dataset. I am placing the values in a table format, and the data changes every hour, which changes the format. I believe that putting the xpath of certain values will help.